# Import assets from bower_components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, adminlte

I installed [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/blog/integrate-adminlte-with-laravel) in Laravel 5.2 by Bower, but cant import assets in view.

I follow step-by-step and my assets not work.

app\resources\views\admin_template.blade.php

```
<link href="{{ asset("/bower_components/AdminLTE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css") }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The files they are bower_components\AdminLTE\bootstrap\css\bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Dump asset(). Is it indicate the corrrct path

Comment: what is displayed in the href ?

Answer (score 1):

try this I think maybe  double quotes is the problem here you can not use right there

```
<link href="{{ asset('/bower_components/AdminLTE/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```